# Após carregar resposta em div sem refresh, atualizar div contendo busca PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, div

A página ja carrega o conteudo em uma div sem refresh, o problema é os seguinte:

Ela carrega a resposta dentro de uma div rem refresh, dando a resposta, preciso que se o produto for adicionado, que ela de refresh tbm na div que mostra os produtos.

Na imagem a parte circulada de azul é a div da resposta e a de vermelho é a que precisa ser atualizada mostrando o novo produto inserido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   //definir evento "onclick" do elemento (botao) ID butEnviar 
   $("#inserir-produto").click(function() {

      //capturar o valor dos campos do fomulario
      var DESCRICAO =  $("input[name=DESCRICAO]").val();
      var TAMANHO =  $("input[name=TAMANHO]").val();
      var COR = $("input[name=COR]").val();
      var QUANTIDADE = $("input[name=QUANTIDADE]").val();
      var VALORUNIT = $("input[name=VALORUNIT]").val();
      var NOME = $("input[name=NOME]").val();
      var OBSERVACAO = $("input[name=OBSERVACAO]").val();
      var botaonome = "inserir-produto";
      var numeropedido = "<? echo $IDPedido; ?>";

       // Exibe mensagem de carregamento
      $("#status").html("<center><img src='template/<? echo $SITE["TEMPLATE"]; ?>/img/load/InternetSlowdown_Day.gif' alt='Enviando' /></center>");
      //usar o metodo ajax da biblioteca jquery para postar os dados em processar.php
      $.ajax({
         "url": "funcoes/teste.php",
         "dataType": "html",
         "data": {
            "DESCRICAO" : DESCRICAO,
            "TAMANHO": TAMANHO,
            "COR" : COR,
            "QUANTIDADE" : QUANTIDADE,
            "VALORUNIT" : VALORUNIT,
            "NOME" : NOME,
            "OBSERVACAO" : OBSERVACAO,
            "botaonome" : botaonome,
            "numeropedido" : numeropedido
         },
         "success": function(response) {
            //em caso de sucesso, a div ID=saida recebe o response do post
            $("div#status").html(response);
         }

      });
   });
});
</script>
```

a Div com o conteudo dos produtos é outra, como faço para ela atualizar mostrando o novo produto adicionado ?

```
    <div class="form-produtos" id="produtos-inseridos">



                                        <?php
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Buscamos e exibimos as mensagens já contidas no banco de dados
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM painel_pedido_itens WHERE pedido='$IDPedido' ORDER BY id DESC");
    if(!mysql_affected_rows($query)){
        echo '
                                        <table border="1" width="100%">                                          
                                        <tr>
                                        <td align="center" width="5%">ID</td>
                                        <td align="center" width="25%">DESCRIÇÃO</td>
                                        <td align="center" width="6%">TAM</td>
                                        <td align="center" width="13%">COR</td>
                                        <td align="center" width="6%">QUANT</td>
                                        <td align="center" width="10%">VALOR UNIT</td>
                                        <td align="center" width="15%">NOME</td>
                                        <td align="center" width="15%">OBSERVAÇÃO</td>
                                        <td align="center" width="5%">OPÇÃO</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        ';

    while($mensagem = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
        echo '
        <tr>
                                        <td align="center" width="5%">' . $mensagem->id . '</td>
                                        <td align="center" width="25%">' . $mensagem->descricao . '</td>
                                        <td align="center" width="6%">' . $mensagem->tamanho . '</td>
                                        <td align="center" width="13%">' . $mensagem->cor . '</td>
                                        <td align="center" width="6%">' . $mensagem->quantidade . '</td>
                                        <td align="center" width="10%">' . $mensagem->valorunit . '</td>
                                        <td align="center" width="15%">' . $mensagem->nome . '</td>
                                        <td align="center" width="15%">' . $mensagem->observacao . '</td>
                                        <td align="center" width="5%"><i class="icon-large icon-remove
"></i></td>
                                        </tr>
        ';      
    }
    echo '</table>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<center>Nenhum produto adicionado</center>";
    }
    ?>
 </div> <!-- /form-actions -->
```

Comment: Tenho impressão que há várias perguntas com esse tipo de dúvida aqui no site. Você pesquisou alguma forma?

Comment: Se quer um submit sem reflesh é com o próprio ajax, não conheço outra forma. Coloque sua instrução no "success" do ajax, dai pode fazer o que quiser em qualquer elemento do html.